# Xamarin Cannot deploy to Emulator or Physical Android

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment, visual-studio-debugging

I have been trying to get a simple Xamarin app to deploy to either an emulator or a physical phone.

The application will run the Xamarin Live player on the physical device, but will not deploy to either phone or emulator.

I am attempting to deploy this in debug mode, here is the end of the build log. 
Would it seem the digital signing is not working?

[image]

EDIT: Environment info

> Windows 10 latest update
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017  Version 15.6.6
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.6.6+27428.2037 Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.7.02556
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual C++ 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA104 Microsoft Visual C++ 2017
>
> Visual F# Tools 10.1 for F# 4.1   00369-60000-00001-AA104 Microsoft
>   Visual F# Tools 10.1 for F# 4.1
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.11.10402.2
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.0.40314.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017
>
> ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   1.0 Provides languages services
>   for ASP.NET Core Razor.
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.51214.0 For additional
>   information, visit https://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.0.40215.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v3.0.0
>
> Azure Data Lake Node   1.0 This package contains the Data Lake
>   integration nodes for Server Explorer.
>
> Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.9000.1 Microsoft Azure
>   Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.9000.1 Microsoft Azure
>   Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   15.0.40215.0 Azure Functions and
>   Web Jobs Tools
>
> C# Tools   2.7.0-beta3-62715-05. Commit Hash:
>   db02128e6e3c4bdfc93e6ec425ac9162b4d4fe80 C# components used in the
>   IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version
>   of the compiler may be used.
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.10 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Cookiecutter   15.6.18072.2 Provides tools for finding, instantiating
>   and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.
>
> EZ-GIT   1.7.3
>
> Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0 Fabric Diagnostic Events
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0 JavaScript UWP Project System
>
> JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2017.3.3    Build 111.0.20180302.65130
>   JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For
>   more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit
>   http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2018 JetBrains, Inc.
>
> Merq   1.1.17-rc (cba4571) Command Bus, Event Stream and Async Manager
>   for Visual Studio extensions.
>
> Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.2.9000.1 HDInsight Node under
>   Azure Node
>
> Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.2.9000.1 Language
>   service for Hive query
>
> Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   2.0 Microsoft
>   Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.2.9000.1
>   Language service for Azure Stream Analytics
>
> Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Node   1.0 Azure Stream Analytics
>   Node under Azure Node
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2017 - v2.9.51212.2
>
> Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.3
>   Simplifying the configuration of continuous build integration and
>   continuous build delivery from within the Visual Studio IDE.
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
>   Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting
>   Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0 Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1 Develop, run,
>   validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5
>   your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL +
>   F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0 Microsoft Visual Studio VC
>   Package
>
> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   4.9.11-pre (71eb098) Support for
>   debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.
>
> NuGet Package Manager   4.6.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0 ProjectServicesPackage Visual
>   Studio Extension Detailed Info
>
> Python   15.6.18072.2 Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates,
>   debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python
>   developers.
>
> Python - Django support   15.6.18072.2 Provides templates and
>   integration for the Django web framework.
>
> Python - IronPython support   15.6.18072.2 Provides templates and
>   integration for IronPython-based projects.
>
> Python - Profiling support   15.6.18072.2 Profiling support for Python
>   projects.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61801.210 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TermWindow Extension   1.0 TermWindow Visual Studio Extension Detailed
>   Info
>
> Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0 Enables Visual Studio's testing
>   tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third
>   Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.
>
> Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0 Enables Visual Studio's testing
>   tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and
>   Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation
>   directory.
>
> ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0 Hosting json editor into a tool window
>
> TypeScript Tools   15.6.20202.3 TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>
> Visual Basic Tools   2.7.0-beta3-62715-05. Commit Hash:
>   db02128e6e3c4bdfc93e6ec425ac9162b4d4fe80 Visual Basic components used
>   in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different
>   version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0 Interop layer for
>   hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Spell Check Everywhere   VSSpellCheckEverywhere An
>   extension that enables spell checking within any Visual Studio file
>   editor or tool window that uses WPF text boxes.
>   https://GitHub.com/EWSoftware/VSSpellChecker
>
> Visual Studio Spell Checker   VSSpellChecker An editor extension that
>   checks the spelling of comments, strings, and plain text as you type
>   or interactively with tool windows.
>   https://GitHub.com/EWSoftware/VSSpellChecker
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova   15.123.7102.2 Visual Studio
>   Tools for Apache Cordova
>
> Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0 Visual Studio Tools for CMake
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Unity   3.6.0.5 Visual Studio Tools for Unity
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.27428.01 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
>
> VisualStudio.Mac   1.0 Mac Extension for Visual Studio
>
> VSShortcutsManager Extension   1.0 VSShortcutsManager Visual Studio
>   Extension Detailed Info
>
> VsVim   2.5.0.0 VsVim is a Vim emulator for Visual Studio
>
> Xamarin   4.9.0.753 (f0f46392f) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin Designer   4.10.96 (a702a9ceb) Visual Studio extension to
>   enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   8.2.0.16 (HEAD/a78295902) Xamarin.Android
>   Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.9.1.24 (f62de47) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: I think the problem is with the apk signing process, have you tampered with it in any way?

Comment: For the project, the signing options are turned off.

Comment: As in Android project properties -> Android Package Signing -> disabled "Sign the .APK file using the following keystore details

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Could not create the Java machine

This error in the picture could be solved by adding an environment variable.
Open Control Panel->System and Security->System->Advanced system settings. Then click environment variables, add a new system variable named `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and set the value to `-Xmx1024M`

You could also solve it by update or reinstall the JDK.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it lead me to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The final resolution was to uninstall ALL versions of Java installed on the machine and ONLY reinstall JDK 8.